# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer is not resizing when parent layer resizes

Tags: ios7, autolayout

I am using AVFoundation for Camera. Here I am adding the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layer to the container view (0,0,786,1024). When I am rotating from portrait to landscape, preview layer is not resizing to containerview.

Note : I am using **Autolayouts** for my application. Application is created for iOS7.0

Below is the code for adding previe layer to container view.

```
- (void)addPreviewLayeInView:(UIView *)aView
{
    if (!session) return;
    
    effectiveScale = 1.0;
    preview = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session];
    preview.frame = aView.bounds;
    preview.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    preview.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    [aView.layer addSublayer:preview];
}
```

Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: Finally. I found the resolution. I have added the below method and changed frame accordingly                                   - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
}